# Is my back bending during my push-up?

Tags: push-ups

So I'm a bit confused. I recorded myself doing pushups and got 3 screenshots

This is my first pushup while coming back up:
[image: Pushup 1]

This is me in my 2nd pushup:
[image: Pushup 2]

And this is me in my 3rd pushup realizing my back is bending:
[image: Pushup 3]

I know this is weird uploading my pictures like this but I want to ask if my back is really bending or if it's just a body posture thing because a lot of people say it isn't.

Comment: Is there anything I can add to my answer to improve it for you?

Answer (score 4):

**Yes.**

You're not keeping your core tight enough. If you're ever not certain if you're in the correct posture, clench your buttock and stomach muscles tight while doing them. By the nature of body mechanics, that will pull you back onto the straight and narrow, and will lead to a better workout because you're maintaining bodily tension. You can relax to a less tense posture once you're certain you're in a correct straight line.

If you're concerned about maintaining proper form during the exercise, a full-length wall mirror can set sideways on a wall, allowing you to quickly glance over and see if your form is good.

Comment: This is the correct answer. As we told you before, do planks. Google correct form.

Comment: so like suck my buttcheeks and stomach in?

Comment: Less "suck in" and more "clench". Trying to "suck in" may cause you to create further imbalance.